# Как залогинить юзера после регистрации при использовании CBV представления ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Всем пример не могу разобраться как залогинить юзера ?  получается что добавить к представлению еще один метод или изменить метод не получается , то есть получается но при аутентификации метод дает значение NONE. как правильно сделать это ?

```
lass UserFormView(CreateView):

    form_class=  MyUserCreationForm
    template_name='registration/reg.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(UserFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

с добавлением авторизации

```
class UserFormView(CreateView):

    form_class=  MyUserCreationForm
    template_name='registration/reg.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        username = self.request.POST['username']
        password = self.request.POST['password2']
        print(username)
        print(password)
        userauth = authenticate(self.request,username=username,password=password)
        print(userauth)
        if userauth is not None:
             if userauth.is_active:
                 login(self.request, userauth)
        return super(UserFormView, self).form_valid(form
```

получается что username и password я получаю и передаю их в метод
но ответ от метода None , погугля можно подумать что он просто не находит такого пользователя потому что он еще не сохранен в бд. но метод form_valid(form) просто берет делает редирект на указынный урл. Если представление написано с логикой не CBV то в нем авторизация работает нормально.